# Filtering Pandas Dataframe using results of group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, group-by

I can't seem to find the solution for this so I figure I would ask as I can imagine this would be a common problem.  I have the following dataframe df:

```
    A   B       Value
0   1   Text 1  Additional comments
1   1   Text 2  TRUE
2   1   Text 3  Apples
3   2   Text 4  Face
4   3   Text 4  Believe
5   4   Text 2  Meat
6   4   Text 9  Chicken
7   5   Text 10 Dairy
8   5   Text 14 Poultry
```

I want to filter this by grouping on Column A and B and eliminating all rows that have a count less than 2, such that the final result of the dataframe will be the removal of row 3 and 4 as shown below

```
    A   B       Value
0   1   Text 1  Additional comments
1   1   Text 2  TRUE
2   1   Text 3  Apples
5   4   Text 2  Meat
6   4   Text 9  Chicken
7   5   Text 10 Dairy
8   5   Text 14 Poultry
```

I understand how to get the group by counts and to filter them:  `dfg = df.groupby(['A','B']).counts()` and `dfg = df.groupby(['A','B']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)` but how do I take this resulting dataframe (dfg) and apply it back into the original dataframe such that I get the results.  I am relatively new to dataframes so it may be obvious, but I have been staring at this for a while.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` and `transform` , then compare:

```
df[df.groupby('A')['A'].transform('size').ge(2)]
```

---

```
   A                B                Value
0  1           Text 1  Additional comments
1  1           Text 2                 TRUE
2  1           Text 3               Apples
5  4           Text 2                 Meat
6  4           Text 9              Chicken
7  5           Text 10               Dairy
8  5           Text 14             Poultry
```

Comment: ge is a direct compare vs a total and how does this work for multiple columns?

Comment: @Jon it counts the items in a group and keeps only those groups where the count of the groups are greater than and equal to 2

Comment: but transform with multiple columns doesn't seem to work in that form?

Comment: @Jon no, for that you have to group on seperate columns and get count of a specific one. if my answer didnt help you please let me know how and  i will try and rectfy it

Comment: the question is how can I use more than one column to get the counts as A and B in the example designate a true sample

Comment: @Jon `df[df.groupby(['A','B'])['Value'].transform('size').ge(2)]` ?